# Prove (~~x=y)→x=y in intuitionistic first order arithmetic

Tags: logic, induction, arithmetic, intuitionistic-logic

Relevant arithmetic axioms and theorems I could prove so far include

Z$(x)=0$

S$(x)\not=0,$S$(x)$=S$(y)\rightarrow x=y$

wffs state that = is an equivalence relation

$x=y\rightarrow \mbox f(...x...)=\mbox f(...y...)$ where f is any expression that represents a primitive recursive function

the first-order induction scheme

$x=0\lor\exists y.x=\mbox S(y)$

~~$x=0\rightarrow x=0$

I know induction should be used but I am not yet able to get to (~~x=Sy)→x=Sy from (~~x=y)→x=y. Thanks.

Comment: I think tat you have to prove by induction that : $\lnot \lnot (t=s) \to (t=s)$.

Comment: @mauro-allegranza Induction in metalanguage or object language? The terms in this logic are relatively complex because there are infinite function constants(every primitive recursive function). The induction axioms A[0/x]→∀x(A→A[S(x)/x])→∀xA are available so object language induction is the direction I want to go.